# elasticsearch Need average per week of some value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have simple data as

```
sales, date_of_sales
```

I need is average per week i.e. sum(sales)/no.of weeks.

Please help.

What i have till now is

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "WeekAggergation": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date_of_sales",
        "interval": "week"
      }
    },
    "TotalSales": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "sales"
      }
    },
    "myValue": {
      "bucket_script": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "myGP": "TotalSales",
          "myCount": "WeekAggergation._bucket_count"
        },
        "script": "params.myGP/params.myCount"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error

```
Invalid pipeline aggregation named [myValue] of type [bucket_script]. 
Only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at the top level.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "WeekAggergation": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date_of_sale",
        "interval": "week",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "TotalSales": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sales"
          }
        },
        "AvgSales": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "sales"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_all_weekly_sales": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "WeekAggergation>TotalSales"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `TotalSales` aggregation is now a nested aggregation under the weekly histogram aggregation (I believe there was a typo in the code provided - the simple schema provided indicated the field name of `date_of_sale` and the aggregation provided uses the plural form `date_of_sales`).  This provides you a total of all sales in the weekly bucket.

Additionally, `AvgSales` provides a similar nested aggregation under the weekly histogram aggregation so you can see the average of all sales specific to that week.

Finally, the pipeline aggregation `avg_all_weekly_sales` will give the average of weekly sales based on the `TotalSales` bucket and the number of non-empty buckets - if you want to include empty buckets, add the `gap_policy` parameter like so:

```
...

"avg_all_weekly_sales": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "WeekAggergation>TotalSales",
        "gap_policy": "insert_zeros"
      }
    }

...
```

(see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-avg-bucket-aggregation.html).

This pipeline aggregation may or may not be what you're actually looking for, so please check the math to ensure the result is what is expected, but should provide the correct output based on the original script.